# Alexa Skills Kit Lambda Region Issue

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to the Alexa Skills Kit and I just want to make a quick hello world skill to test it out, I've set up a lambda account for the endpoint for said skill, and I tried to create a lambda server but it says that it is not available in my region. I live in southern california, do I have to be in the region to use and host the skills code on lambda?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use US-East as per the Alexa documentation..

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/deploying-a-sample-skill-to-aws-lambda

Note: Lambda functions for Alexa skills must be hosted in the US East (N. Virginia) region. Currently, this is the only Lambda region the Alexa Skills Kit supports.

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/en-GB/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html#select-the-optimal-region-for-your-aws-lambda-function

Answer (score 2):

To more specifically answer your question: "No, you don't have to be in any particular region to use the US-East Lambda region".

And as stated above, you current must select the US-East region to support Alexa skills.

Comment: Select US-East region to support Alexa skills? I am sorry, not following. Where does this happen?

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu There are multiple ways to specify your AWS region, depending on how you are running your code. [Maybe start here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html).